# What Should Be the M in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In an MVVM architecture, where should the model be? Does the client have to have a seperate model (which we might call client model) or can we consider the web API the client is communicating with as the "M" in MVVM.

It might be more helpful to explain it over an example. Let's say we have a WPF application for shopping (which is tightly integrated to the server as opposed to a calculator like application). When a customer adds a product to the cart, "AddProductToCart(product)" is called via Web API and returns "OK" on successful operation completion. Then, should we keep a cart object at the client side as well and add the newly added product object to cart? Or rather than keeping such a state, should we just update the UI, notifying the customer of the successful aoperation and when the user navigates to another page that requires the knowledge of products in the cart, the client queries the web API and get the fresh data?

If such a model does not exist at the client, then server can return DTO's which can be used as the view model. But otherwise, I guess I will need to keep some kind of a modified version of the business model at the client side(since it would not be right to use the business model entities for the client model). Would that be more in line with the MVVM architecture? If so, is there a best practice for the formation of that model? Because I guess it will need flattening and will requre holding some view specific fields, too.

Comment: The **Model** is obviously the database or server DB that contains the data. In the example scenario you proposed, it is obviously a  DB or data source which contains the data of all products. In client side you can have a DB or not, it is optional. But you can have model classes definitely, ie a `Product` data class that is basically the prototype of the products. For eg: it can consists of Product name, description, price, image path, etc. Since the data is dynamic you need to call the web api to fetch the data from the server. You fetch the `List<ProductData> Products` from your model.

Comment: What if the user left the application running on his home computer with one item in the cart, went to work, and added two items from his phone? Synchonization becomes a nightmare. When he gets back home and adds a fourth item, `AddProductToCart()` should return the full current state of the shopping cart. This isn't an MVVM issue. ["When in doubt, use brute force"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot). The client should keep a copy if it's something the client needs a copy of. A shopping cart is probably such a thing. You're asking for a general answer to a very specific question.